# How to print all friends's name?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am currently using JS SDK and PHP SDK. I need a simple way to display all friends's names and friends' pictures.

I can display pictures by using this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture
```

but I don't know how to display the names.

Comment: Friends of friends or Friends?

Comment: xRobot, you just cant code by asking questions. Follow the docs on facebook. Try them. If you fail, then ask here. :) And marku questions as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=the_token` will give the list of your friends in JSON.

[Refer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) this. You can click on that 'Friends' link  to see the output, However please note that the API Docs page is using an access_token which **will expire** soon .

Comment: So, do I have to do an http request ( curl ? ) and then parse the json with json_decode ( in PHP ) ? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes. But before that you need to obtain the access_token. That needs a whole lot more code. :) .

Comment: Refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) for authentication steps.

Comment: @xRobot Mark this as solution if this is what you wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Make a call to the graph api and print the response,

```
FB.api('/me/friends/?access_token='+accessToken, function(response) {
    for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
        var friend = response.data[i];
        var friends = friend.name;
        console.log(friends);
    }
});
```

Also it's possible to get back only the required fields and not all the user object,

```
    FB.api('/me/friends/?fields=name&access_token='+accessToken, function(response) {
        for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
            var friend = response.data[i];
            var friends = friend.name;
            console.log(friends);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

With jQuery you can use append() to print the names and the images also:

```
FB.api('/me/friends/?fields=name,id&access_token='+accessToken, function(response) {
    for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++) {
        var friend = response.data[i];
        var content = friend.name+'<br>'
                    + '<img src="//graph.facebook.com/'+friend.id+'/picture"/><br>';
        $('#container').append(content);
    }
});
```